# What is the event called when you select a previously entered input on a text input?

Tags: events, backbone.js, input, event-handling, mouseevent

What is this event called? I currently have a change listener on Backbone listening to this input, but when I select one of the previously entered values, it doesn't trigger this event.

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

3.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used Chrome Dev Tool's #monitorEvents and found that this autoComplete type of event is called an 'input'